# expo-barcode-scanner - After closing the app the camera symbol stays in the right corner

Tags: react-native, expo, qr-code, barcode-scanner, react-component-unmount

I'm trying to make a qr code scanner with the expo-barcode-scanner in react native. Everything works fine but when I exit the application (It still run in the background), the camera symbol in the top right corner stays there like this:

[image: Example]

I just copy/pasted the example from expo and It's still do the same thing.

Any suggestions?

I'm not sure but I think that I need to unmount somehow the permission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue with navigation.

After unmounting the component the problem disappeared.
It is even described in the [Expo](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/bar-code-scanner/) documentation

> When using navigation, the best practice is to unmount any previously rendered BarCodeScanner component so the following screens can use their own BarCodeScanner without any issue.

Hope it will help!